# What is the most efficient way to write 3GB of data to datastore?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a 3Gb csv file. I would like to write all of the data to GAE datastore. I have tried reading the file row by row and then posting the data to my app, but I can only create around 1000 new entities before I exceed the free tier and start to incur pretty hefty costs. What is the most efficient / cost effective way to upload this data to datastore?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store each row as a separate entity, it does not matter how you create these entities - you can improve the performance by batching your requests, but it won't affect the costs.

The costs depend on how many indexed properties you have in each entity. Make sure that you only index the properties that you need to be indexed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are over 19M entities that need to be created, with 16 properties per entity. I believe that this would mean 2 x 19M calls to the datastore (2 writes per put) and from this link (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) that would cost (38M / 100k * $0.06 = $22.80)? The thing is that to write ~ 1000 new entities is using up the free quota (50k) - quite a bit more than 2 writes per entity.

Comment: As I mentioned, you also have 2 write operations per each indexed property. Unless you mark all 16 properties as unindexed, your costs will be 34 writes per entity instead of 2.

Comment: Wow! I misunderstood - I thought properties would only be indexed if there was an explicit index created in index.yaml . So to write this to datastore would cost (ignoring free quota) ~$364.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is use a mapper. Is it all one file? If so break it up into as many smaller files as you can then use a mapper to fill the DB. The reason you break them up is the mapper sends each file to its own thread. So the more files the more threads you have the faster it will do the work.

Read up on [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) and [Mapreduce](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki) for more info

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

```
def get(self):
    bucketName = "" #Bucketname
    listOfFiles = gcs.listbucket("/" + bucketName + "path to folder with the files")

    pipeline = Mapreduce(bucketName, listOfFiles)
    pipeline.start()
    self.redirect(pipeline.base_path + "/status?root=" + pipeline.pipeline_id)

class Mapreduce(base_handler.PipelineBase):
    def run(self, bucketName, listOfFiles):
        yield mapper_pipeline.MapperPipeline(
            "Fill Data",
            "main.FillDB",
            "mapreduce.input_readers._GoogleCloudStorageInputReader",
            params = {"input_reader" : {
                                 "bucket_name" : bucketName,
                                 "objects" : listOfFiles
                                 }                                 
                             },

            shards=64)

def FillDB(data):
    for line in data:
        infoForDb = line.split(",")
        inputDB = EntityName(id=infoForDb[0], productName=infoForDb[1])
        db.put(inputDB)
    return
```

Comment: The question is about the costs, not speed.

Comment: The OP has mentioned **efficient** as well. Using MapReduce is a very good way to migrating data into datastore.